# Why am I getting error 'Cannot read property 'name' of null' when using a parsed string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, object

Here I have a react container that holds an object in a variable called strLoc:

(what var strLoc looks like console logged)

> Object {name: "Burj Khalifa", locationLat: "25.197787", locationLong:
>   "55.274862"}

I want to use the name property of the object, but when I try to get {strLoc.name}, I get an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

I don't understand why I can't just pull off the property values to use them? Does the problem have something to do with that the object was a string before (I parsed the string and saved the resulting object in var strLoc) ?

here is my code:

```
class NoteOutput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var strLoc = JSON.parse(this.props.location); 
        return(
            <div>
                <div>hello</div>
                <div>{strLoc.name}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        location: state.selectedLocation
    };
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.props.location`?

Comment: {"name":"Burj Khalifa","locationLat":"25.197787","locationLong":"55.274862"} is the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its probably because you have the parse in your render() and it tries to show .name of a string/before it gets parsed.

try this:

```
{strLoc && <div>{strLoc.name}</div>}
```

Comment: it worked! Does this code basically instruct the parsed var strLoc to be created before using the object to get to the name property? Just trying to understand what the code means, will research it now anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @user74843 its basically saying if strLoc exists, render this. its like an if block

Comment: Basically on the first render 'this.props.location' is null, as I'm assuming it's an async result and as @Luna said, you need a check to see if it actually exists before rendering it

Comment: JSON.parse is synchronous, if he wants to really be sure, he can do a console.log in componentWillReceiveProps and see what he gets from the props. JSON.parse(null) returns null

Comment: And if this.props.location is not null from the first render, it will not re-render at all because React components render on state or props change, not on JSON.parse  or any async actions inside that doesn't affect state or props